# nivo-slider no link to the image when download

Tags: jquery, html, css, download, slider

Hello all is it only me when i try to download the nivo slider http://nivo.dev7studios.com/

there is NO link to the image in the /images/ map in the CSS file or so :S.

Comment: you need to be more specific. maybe its in the html file

Comment: it is not i the html file :/ try download the zip file and look :O

Comment: what do you mean? everything is there for me. What are you missing?

Comment: im missing the link to the images in the images folder, its not in the CSS file (the style)

Comment: you see here no styleing http://img834.imageshack.us/i/skrmbillede20110324kl23.png/

Comment: This is the files i got http://img10.imageshack.us/i/skrmbillede20110324kl23.png/  With the image folder to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images are in the html file

```
<div id="slider-wrapper">

            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                <img src="images/toystory.jpg" alt="" />
                <img src="images/up.jpg" alt="" title="This is an example of a caption" /></a>
                <img src="images/walle.jpg" alt="" />
                <img src="images/nemo.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption" />
            </div>
```

Comment: yes but the images toystory.jpg etc. are not in the images folder.. and the image that are in the image folder now dont show up on the page

Comment: why don't you just redownload it?? It works fine with a fresh download. I don't understand what you're trying to do